# Why is undefined: error thrown while passing custom struct as pointers?

Tags: go, struct, undefined

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type CustomInfo struct {
        Name string
        Size int
    }

    type Error struct {
        ErrorCode int
        ErrorMsg  string
    }
    type Product struct {
        Fruit string
        CInfo CustomInfo
        Err   Error
    }

    var pr1 = Product{
        Fruit: "Orange",
        CInfo: CustomInfo{
            Name: "orango botanica",
            Size: 3,
        },
        Err: Error{
            ErrorMsg:  "",
        },
    }

    var pr2 = Product{
        Fruit: "Apple",
        CInfo: CustomInfo{
            Name: "appleo botanica",
            Size: 4,
        },
        Err: Error{
            ErrorMsg:  "",
        },
    }

    var products []Product
    products = append(products, pr1, pr2)
    mrshl, _ := json.Marshal(products)

    var productsRes []Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(mrshl), &productsRes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //fmt.Println(productsRes[0].Fruit)
    //fmt.Println(productsRes[1])
    //fmt.Println(unmrshl)
    validate(&productsRes)
}

func validate(bRes *Product){
    fmt.Println(bRes[0].Fruit)
    fmt.Println(bRes[1])
}
```

Why do I get `./prog.go:61:22: undefined: Product` ?

Comment: Ok. After making some modifications https://play.golang.org/p/51Q7TxnkNHz , now I get following output ```&[{Orange {orango botanica 3} {0 }} {Apple {appleo botanica 4} {0 }}]```

1) Why is it showing & in the output?
2) How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your updated playground example a bit [here](https://play.golang.org/p/uY8YWfd_wcK).

You don't want a *pointer to* the slice, you just want to pass the slice itself. It's not inherently wrong to pass a pointer, it's just unnecessary here.  A slice means: "I (`main`) give you (`validate`) access to an array I have made."  The slice header provides the user-of-the-slice:

- access to the array (via indexing: `bRes[i]` is the *i*-th element of the array);
- the length of the array: `len(bRes)`—the `for` loops use this implicitly; and
- the capacity of the array (not used in this example).

By writing to `bRes[i]` we can update any or all of the fields of one of the `Product`s in the underlying array.  This is what the second loop I added to `validate` does.

Note: lines 47-48, which read:

> ```
> var products []Product
> products = append(products, pr1, pr2)
> ```

uses `append` a little oddly: since we just have the two products, we could build the slice directly with:

```
products := []Product{pr1, pr2}
```

The value of `products` will be `nil` initially.  The nil slice header says, in effect, that the length and capacity are both zero, and there is no underlying array after all.  Appending to a `nil` slice always causes `append` to allocate a new underlying array.  The `append` function returns the new slice, which uses the new array.<sup>1</sup>  So there's a tiny bit of wasted effort in setting up this nil slice, only to throw it out.  Again, it's not *wrong*, it's just unnecessary.

(Meanwhile, you get +1 point for checking for an error from `json.Unmarshal`, but -1 point, or maybe minus half a point, for *not* checking for an error from `json.Marshal`. )

---

<sup>1</sup>`append` *always* constructs a new slice header.  The new header may re-use the old array, in some cases. or it may use a new array.  The `append` operation will re-use the old, already-existing array if and only if the appended elements fit into the existing array based on the capacity indicated by the original slice header.  Since a `nil` header has a capacity of zero, its existing array cannot be used here.

Comment: When should one send a pointer and when shouldn't. By the way, amazing analysis and writing. I wish I had a teacher like you. 

Comment: But if I'm running through a for loop and adding element at an array, append is the only way, right?

Comment: I assume slice header means starting index of the slice

Comment: No, a slice header is what a slice variable itself holds. There are three parts to the slice header, as listed in the bullet points above, so if you're really comfortable with `struct` you can think of the three parts as a sort of `struct`. A variable declared with `var s []T` (for some type `T`) is therefore treated by the compiler as `type SliceHeader struct { ...three-parts... }` and then `var s SliceHeader`, except that you can't actually access the three parts like that.

Comment: Here's a good pictorial diagram: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals (and there's another link to this in the Go Tour after you go through https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7).

Answer (score 1):

Your struct definition is in `main` and thus out of scope for `validate`, it can only be used inside of your main function. It should work when you move your struct definitions out of `main`

Also, your `validate` function should probably accept a `[]Product` (slice of `Product`), not a `*Product` (pointer to single `Product`)

Comment: I moved the structs outside main( ). 

Yeah, I did get some other error, and now fixing the ```validate``` function. 
1. Shouldn't validate function be ```validate(bRes *[ ]Product)``` ?
2. But how can I index bRes now?